# Put a variable from controller to view

Tags: php, symfony

All examples that I studied until now are putting the results from controller to view using an array. That is the only option?

I did here a script that is giving me the prime numbers from 1 to 100.

Controller

```
class NumbersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($n=5)
    {
            for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){  //numbers to be checked as prime
                $counter = 0;
                for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){ //all divisible factors
                    if($i % $j==0){
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
                //prime requires 2 rules ( divisible by 1 and divisible by itself)
                if($counter==2){
                echo $i . ",";  
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

What options do I have to put the numbers from $i in my view?
I tried to do it using the array but I get just the first number so I guess that isn't an option.

```
    {{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Numbers:index', { 'n': 100 })) }}
```

I setted a prefix for routes, so I can access it on `symfony/web/app_dev.php/numbers/`

Comment: Have you tried to used an array to store the values?

Comment: I thought about it but don't make any sense for me. Symfony should make this stuffs easier not more complicated.

Comment: Once you call `return`, the `indexAction` function will stop running. In your example `$i` is a loop variable; if your `return` is inside the `for` loop it will stop after one iteration.

Comment: That make perfect sense. What alternative do I have?

Comment: @crixi: you really should read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you still do not have basic understanding of symfony2.

You can build an array of data within your controller and pass it to the render method while returning it and this is the correct way to do it.

Use following code with your own modifications:

Controller:

```
class NumbersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction($n=5)
    {
        $data = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
        {
            // numbers to be checked as prime
            $counter = 0;

            for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
                // all divisible factors
                if ($i % $j == 0) {
                    $counter++;
                }
            }

            // prime requires 2 rules ( divisible by 1 and divisible by itself)
            if ($counter == 2) {
                $data[] = $i;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
    }
}
```

Twig File (index.html.twig):

```
{{ data|join(',') }}
```

Comment: Sounds nice but `Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! `

Comment: can you update your question with your routing, controller and twig file contents

Comment: I have modified my answer which should work for you.